# How to use tokens in a node?

Tags: 8, nodes, tokens

I added a new content type. How can I use tokens when editing a node of that content type?

For example, if I put "*Hello [user:name]*", the page shows the following:

[image]

As shown above, the "*[user:name]*" token in it is not replaced with the username.

Answer (score 5):

You need a text filter to replace tokens in fields. You can configure them in `admin/config/content/formats`. In drupal 7 you can install the needed text filter with:

[Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter)

But this will not be ported to drupal 8 in the same way as in drupal 7:

[Issue Token Filter in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2595149)

As this is a very simple piece of code, there is an unofficial version for drupal 8:

[token_filter-8.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/2207363)

Comment: it works like to drupal7 or Drupal8 works differently?

Comment: With token_filter_8.x it works like in drupal 7. This is not an official drupal 8 port and I'm not sure, if this works 100 % for all kind of tokens. There may be some caching issues.

Answer (score 4):

This is something one typically does with the [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) module. Some details from its project page:

> Token Filter is a very simple module to make token values available as an input filter.
>
> The module now supports native tokens (e.g. [site:name]) and all global tokens by default. It even allows some contextual tokens like node or user to be replaced, but currently does not encourage users to use them in the filter help text.

This module currently has a [beta version](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter/releases/8.x-1.0-beta1) for D8.

Comment: This is the definitive answer for Drupal 7